# How to include LinkedIn user profile page feeds in web application?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, linkedin-api

I am building a web application in which I would like to include the user's LinkedIn profile page feeds. Is this possible?

What I envision is the user comes to the web application and adds the complete URL for their Linked user profile in a text box and I would get the feeds for that user page.

Would it be possible to do this with jquery? Or should I be looking at some other tool?

I trying to make it more clear,

I want to create a widget kinda of app for my web app where user enters a complete url of the linkedin user profile page and I have to retrieve the feeds of that particular user and display it.

It should be dynamic in nature, if another user enters a another url into the text box I should be able to get the feeds from that particular user profile page.

Comment: How does jQuery or jQuery UI relate to this? You need to use some requests to LinkedIn API, but not using jQuery. Curl for example is a better solution in this task.

Comment: While this was a poorly written question - I have edited and cleaned it up - I don't think that warrants voting it down. If you think a question is poorly written, then edit it, rather than voting it down. I have voted it up to clear the down vote.

Comment: @Coolesh: I am using jquery at the front end and I feeds which I get from the linked in will be either in the form of JSON or ATOM so I have ti represent in HTML format.Thats the reason I said jquery.

Comment: @Jordon: thank you jordon I am a novice developer and also new to stackoverflow.com. Thanks a lot for cleaning my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be retrieving the user's 'Network Updates', the series of actions that a given user's connections have taken (such as making new connections, updating their profile, etc) that is displayed when you log in to LinkedIn, correct?

The LinkedIn API allows you to retrieve a user's network updates once they have authenticated your application.  More information about registering an application can be found here:

http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis

Once you have the application registered, you can then integrate the API into your site via JavaScript, PHP, etc and make a call to the Network Updates API:

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1006